# Autowired failed with null result when running test with TestNG and Spring context

Tags: java, spring, maven, nullpointerexception, inversion-of-control

I am construct the spring using maven  , I dont know where i am wrong, spring ioc i have add this beans but still appear the follow error

```
[TestNG] Running:
C:\Users\lw\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-280706424\testng-customsuite.xml

null
[Utils] Attempting to create D:\lw\workspace\spring\test-output\Default    suite\Default test.xml
[Utils]   Directory D:\lw\workspace\spring\test-output\Default suite exists:   true
FAILED: testIOC
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.syz.test01.AppTest.testIOC(AppTest.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.j ava:100)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1137)
at  org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129 )
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:753)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:607)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:368)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:363)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:321)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:270)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1284)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1209)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1124)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1096)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)


===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

web.xml

```
 <web-app>
 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
 </web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.syz.test01" />
</beans>
```

Person.java

```
package com.syz.test01;
@Component
public class Person {
public String name = "zhangsan";

public String age = "1";

public String getName() {

    return name;

}

public void setName(String name) {

    this.name = name;

}

public String getAge() {

    return age;

}

public void setAge(String age) {

    this.age = age;

    }
}
```

App.java

```
package com.syz.test01;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
@Component
public class App {
@Autowired
public Person person;

public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
}

public void setPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
}

public  void testIOC()

{
    System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Apptest.java

```
package com.syz.test01;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:applicationContext.xml" })
public class AppTest {
@Autowired
public App app ;

public App getApp() {
    return app;
}
public void setApp(App app) {
    this.app = app;
}
@Test
public void testIOC() {
    System.out.println(app);
    System.out.println(app.getPerson().getName());
    }
}
```

Person.java

```
package com.syz.test01;
@Component
public class Person {
public String name = "zhangsan";

public String age = "1";

public String getName() {

    return name;

}

public void setName(String name) {

    this.name = name;

}

public String getAge() {

    return age;

}

public void setAge(String age) {

    this.age = age;

    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>spring</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>spring</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHbUL.png)

Comment: What is line 20 of AppTest.java?

Comment: From the error message, it is most likely `System.out.println(app.getPerson().getName());`. The error tells you that either `app` is `null` or `getPerson()` returns `null`. You need to determine which it is and why.

Comment: i use testNG to test the springIOC function ,line 20 of AppTest.java is to test the method testIOC() in the App.java

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. I was asking which exact line causes the error. The error message you posted says it is line 20 of AppTest.java. I cannot count that high, so you should clearly label which line this is. You can find the cause of the error on that line and start from there.

Comment: in AppTest.java ,i have Autowired an App,In App i hava Autowired an Person,why still null ,this is the mater i dont understand

Comment: You need to use a debugger to double check that your autowiring actually works the way you think it does. Alternatively, you can add `System.out.println()` calls to your code to view the values of variables.

Comment: I threw the code into my compiler. Line 20 is the second to last bracket.

Comment: i use debugger , System.out.println(app),the app is null,  but i have Autowired App in the AppTest, why still null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your beans are loaded by the "component-scan", you must annotate your components with `@Component`:

```
@Component
public class Person {
....
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class App {
....
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The test class *AppTest.java* must be annotated with `@ContextConfiguration`:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
```

make sure TestNG can see and load the file applicationContext.xml by correcting its path.

**UPDATE 2:**

To get works, you might need to add dependency to spring-test in your pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Add this to *AppTest.java*:

```
@org.junit.runner.RunWith(org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

This instruct junit to execute test as a Spring test.

Note that `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` only works with junit 4.5+, so update your dependency of junit to latest:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**COMPLETE**

Here is complete working *AppTest.java*. Note that some testng annotations have been replaced by junit for compatibility with Spring test framework.

```
package com.syz.test01;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@org.junit.runner.RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:applicationContext.xml" })
public class AppTest{
    @Autowired
    public App app;

    public App getApp() {
        return app;
    }
    public void setApp(App app) {
        this.app = app;
    }
    @org.junit.Test
    public void testIOC() {
        System.out.println(app);
        System.out.println(app.getPerson().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: i add @Component  in the tow place but the app is null

Comment: after add it tell me:ContextConfiguration cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: ContextConfiguration is from spring-test (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test/4.3.4.RELEASE). Add spring-test to your pom.xml and import ContextConfiguration to your AppTest

Comment: i have edit the code According to your method then i test the AppTest.java by TestNG,the result i have edit in the code,i really dont know where is wrong.

Comment: From your stacktrace, I suspected that the issue relates to the way you execute the test, how did you do that ? In Eclipse or from command line ? I guess Spring IOC has not been involved in the test execution, so the beans were not injected correctly.

Comment: System.out.println(app);in AppTest.java show the app is null.In fact  i Autowired App into AppTest.java,it will not be null.but now it is null.strange

Comment: In Eclipse ,Right-click on the Apptest.java  then Run as , choice the TestNGtest

Comment: i have put the project  on github theaddressis : git@github.com:liwei-green/spring.git

Comment: thank you very much  ,Problem has been solved . but could you tell me why use testNG Autowired failure.

Comment: Spring test framework works with both TestNg and junit, however, in different ways. But your code is just only a plain TestNg code, it doesn't tell TestNg it is a Spring test case so the Spring context is not loaded at all. To use TestNg, you must let AppTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You aren't giving any values to your Person class in your app class. So that means in AppTester, when it calls `app.getPerson` it is sending a null value.

Comment: BeanFactory bf = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");  App at = (App) bf.getBean("app");  i use this method is right ,Is it possible to that Autowired do not create beans?